# Is the practice of lobbying in the United States as it exists today constitutional?

Tags: united-states, democracy, lobbying

A core principle of The Declaration of Independence, [Popular Sovereignty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_sovereignty), is the idea that a government only exists to serve the will of the individuals it represents.

I understand this to mean that all people are considered equally, and no one citizen should have more say than the next.

Does the practice of lobbying, where a small group of individuals fund politicians in exchange for their cooperation, really adhere to the Democracy the Founding Fathers looked to create?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77001).